# How to transfer GTA V save files?

Tags: steam, pc, grand-theft-auto-v

How can you transfer your save files from one computer to another?
I can't find any function on Social Club or steam.

Answer (score 19):

Configuration Files will be stored in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V\`,
while the Save Data will be stored in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V\Profiles\(user-id)`

[Source](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_V#Save_game_data_location)

Comment: @William did copying the files into a new computer work for you?