# Save File Import

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

My SSD went belly up, but I managed to salvage my GTA V saves. However, when I place them in my profile folder (C:/Users/:User:/Documents/Rockstar Games/GTA V/Profiles/:Profile:), as per [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/214394), GTA doesn't seem to recognize the save. If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or how to fix, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you take a look at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/214394 and see if that solves your question?

Comment: Ive seen this post, as my question says, that is where I attempted to put my save files to no avail. :(

Comment: Are they actually your save files? I hate to ask but I do believe these are tied to your account and so people can not trade progress which is tracked by the social system embedded into GTA V.

Comment: They would appear to be, I tested this by taking out the save file named the exact same thing that I had from just playing through the prologue to get to online, and once I did GTA reset me to a new game.

Answer (score 9):

**For me, it works this way:**

You have 2 files for 1 savegame, for example:
SGTA50000
SGTA50000.bak

You need both of them in the folder (C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V\Profiles\SC_NUMBER). Try deleting all older savegames.

Restart the game and click on "Story Mode", the save will load automatically.

**If this doesn't work:**

1. Backup the "Rockstar Games" folder (C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Rockstar Games\)
2. Delete the whole Rockstar Games folder (C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Rockstar Games\) => This is safe, I also did that. But your game settings will be gone if you don't back it up.
3. Restart the game, the folder will be re-created new with all the needed data.
4. Put your newest savegame-files into the folder (both files): C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V\Profiles\SC_NUMBER\
5. Restart and try again.

Answer (score 6):

Trudler is right, but for Steam version they are at:

```
C:\ProgramData\Socialclub\YOUR_SOCIAL_ID\NUMBER
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Reloaded version, go to this directory:

```
C:\ProgramData\Socialclub\RLD!
```

Your save games are in this subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there this will work for sure:

- List item
- Go to local disk C
- Now click on view option from the toolbar

  - Or jus press alt+v+h+h
- Now you will see a folder hidden named `ProgramData`
- Open it. Find `Social Club`
- Open it. You will see a folder `RLD`!
- Open it and you will have 2 folders
- Choose a folder similar to this: `271590` (or it may be different).
- Now paste your new save game here