# How to install a savegame?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I have downloaded GTA V on PC, I want to install a savegame but there is nothing in profiles folder. I tried installing savegames but it didnt work.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Do you mean to load a previously saved game?

Comment: No, i never had files in the profile folder

Comment: If you don't have a previous game save then what are you trying to install?

Comment: I assume you mean the 'savegame' folder isn't there? If you start a new game and save it, the folder should then appear and you can add in the save you wish

Comment: THese are the files   https://mega.co.nz/#!SZQzHYIA!UGWrpbZVjxjqKfvHhvQHu-L7UmFF52KUZaPHjhnAieg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save File Import](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/215254/save-file-import)